# Update Collection value

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update a column in a `Collection` but nothing seems to work.
Tried `update` and `$kk->amount = 100` and `['amount'] = 100` but none of that is working.

```
$newReturnBoxes = collect([
        {
            "boxable_id": 2,
            "box_id": 1,
            "boxable_type": "return",
            "amount": 3,
            "created_at": "2022-03-29T08:29:03.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-03-29T08:29:03.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "boxable_id": 3,
            "box_id": 1,
            "boxable_type": "return",
            "amount": 4,
            "created_at": "2022-03-29T08:32:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-03-29T08:32:02.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "boxable_id": 3,
            "box_id": 2,
            "boxable_type": "return",
            "amount": 2,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }
    ]);

$returnBoxes->each(function ($trx) use ($newReturnBoxes) {
            $amount = $trx->amount;
            $boxId = $trx->box_id;

            if ($newReturnBoxes->contains('box_id', $boxId)) {
                // Already contains key, increment amount
                $kk = $newReturnBoxes->firstWhere('box_id', $boxId);
                $kk['amount'] = 100; // actually want to increase prev amount with current amount
                
            } else {
                $newReturnBoxes->push([
                    'box_id' => $boxId,
                    'amount' => $amount
                ]);
            }
        });
```

Comment: In your code example you're not setting a proper PHP array inside the collection. You're trying to put a mix of an array and json inside the collection.

Comment: @Mark oh it's more a copy paste error for the question, indeed the `$newReturnBoxes` is a valid collection.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the problem is that you are not passing the `$newReturnBoxes` by reference.

Try to replace this:

```
use ($newReturnBoxes)
```

With this:

```
use (&$newReturnBoxes)
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php